# DnaA binding energy to E coli genome

Tags: molecular-biology, microbiology, dna-replication, protein-binding, binding-sites

I have been told that DnaA binds strongly to DnaA boxes on the E coli genome, but binds weakly to 8 out of 11 sites near ori. I want to know more quantitatively what strongly and weekly mean. Are there order of magnitude estimates of binding energies of DnaA to various locations on the E. coli genome?

Comment: I would suggest searching the literature for answers, I didn't instantly find binding energies but I could readily find [dissociation constant estimates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1170261/pdf/006574.pdf).

Comment: @MaximilianPress Thank you, this is helpful. I had done a quick search and hadn't found anything, but I wasn't searching for dissociation constants, which is equally useful. Feel free to post this as an answer, and I will accept it.